# finding sub type over flow in ada

Tags: overflow, numeric, ada, subtype

I am trying to find ways for identifying sub type over flow errors in Ada language automatically.

below is the Ada language syntax.

```
C :=  A + B;

-- A is sub type of [-3  3]
-- B is sub type of [-2 2]
-- C is sub type of [-3  3]
```

what i want is, tool should use min, max, median of the input parameters and record if any over flow occurs in the destination parameter.

for example for max. value of A that is 3 and max. value of B (2) , there will be over flow in the C variable.

I am having 5000 files which I need to ensure above type of errors not present. I am looking for ways to do it automatically.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What do you mean "trying to find ways" ... when I simply execute that line of code with inappropriate values, the overflow error is detected automatically.`raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : main.adb:11 range check failed` The only wrinkle is that if your compiler is an obsolete version of Gnat, you need to add the `-gnato` compiler option to turn on a check that ought to be on anyway. But that's been fixed since about gcc4.8.

Comment: Sir, I am having 5000 files which I need to ensure above type of errors not present. I am looking for ways to do it automatically.

Comment: Keep on dreaming. There is no fully automatic way to do this - testcase coverage is one way to get close to the goal, but you need to have sufficient coverage for this. SPARK is another but then you need to write the appropriate SPARK code.

Comment: Sir, how to do using SPARK?

Comment: So,by "find automatically" you mean at compile time rather than runtime? That info should have been in the  question. Then,  @darkestkhan is right, use SPARK. Start here. http://www.spark-2014.org/

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy if you know all your values at compile time. And it will be a bit complicated otherwise. But you will always get Constraint_Error at runtime if you violate any constraints.

```
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is 
   subtype A_T is Integer range -3..3;
   subtype B_T is Integer range -2..2;
   subtype C_T is Integer range -3..3;

   A : A_T := 3;
   B : B_T := 2;
   C : C_T;

   AA : A_T := 1;
   BB : B_T := 1;
   CC : C_T;

   AAA : A_T;
   BBB : B_T;
   CCC : C_T;
begin

   C := A + B; -- Not ok warning: value not in range of type C_T,
   -- Constraint_Error will be riased at run time

   CC := AA + BB; -- OK, no overflow detected at compile time

   Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(AAA); -- impossible to check at compile time, 
   Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(BBB); -- Constraint_Error will be raised at runtime if constraint violated
   CCC := AAA + BBB;
end Main;
```